# Select File from folder

Tags: excel, vba

Request to help me on below query.
From a folder I want the file to be selected, I could retrieve the file name but could not select the file in folder, should just highlight the file. I am using the objFile.Name.Select but it is through exception as object required 424

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Desktop\New folder")
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    MsgBox objFile.Name
    objFile.Name.Select
   If InStr(objFile.Name, "Document Error") > 0 Then
       Exit For
   End If
Next objFile
```

Comment: I have the code ready but I want to understand the purpose of selecting it?

Comment: What does that mean "Selected"? Select seems pretty meaningless in this context. What are you ACTUALLY wanting to do here? You say "Highlight" but FSO isn't a file dialog for the user to look at.

Comment: If I select, I can perform the right click and integrate it with tool to perform necessary action, @ sidddharth rout  it will be great help if you share

Comment: If the the file name is returned as Test.xlsx, that file should be selected (like a single click) in the window -  JNevill

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim objFSO As Object, objFolder As Object, objFile As Object
    Dim sFolder As String

    sFolder = "C:\Users\Desktop\New folder"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(sFolder)

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        MsgBox objFile.Name
        Shell "explorer.exe /select,""" & sFolder & "\" & objFile.Name & """", vbNormalFocus
        If InStr(objFile.Name, "Document Error") > 0 Then Exit For
    Next objFile
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot Siddharth. Thats what my requirement was. Thnak you once again

Comment: One common query, while I am trying to handle error during SAP development in VBA Excel, sometimes On Error Resume Next instead of passing the error shows an error message as 'control not found'. Can you advise on this any alternate way to skip the error if you are comfortable

Comment: Is this query related to the above question?

Comment: No, this is something I faced while developing code for SAP in Macro

Comment: Then please post a new question for this :)